# Any advantages of converting string variable to int using stoi?

Tags: c++

What's the benefit of converting the variable from `string` to `int` using `std::stoi`?

I saw a lecture and it declares string variable and converts it to `int` later. Any reason for doing this? or it's just a preference?

I don't think using `stoi` in the given code is necessary.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string sAge = "0";
    int nGrade = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter age: ";
    getline (std::cin, sAge);
    int nAge = std::stoi(sAge);

    if ((nAge >= 1) && (nAge <= 18)) {
        std::cout << "Important Birthday" << std::endl;
    }
    else if ((nAge == 21) || (nAge == 50)) {
        std::cout << "Important Birthday" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (nAge >= 65) {
        std::cout << "Important Birthday" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not an important Birthday" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0; }
```

Comment: What happens if you try to do `sAge >= 1` without converting? Have you tried that?

Comment: If you don't convert the string to an `int`, how would you expect things like `nAge >= 1` to work?

Comment: If he's teaching C++ he should have used `cin >> nAge` instead of `stoi()`.

Comment: the lecture was just teaching about if statement, so i was wondering why he is using stoi instead of cin >> nAge, maybe he wanted to teach an additional thing?

Comment: No point in asking us what's in his head.

Comment: When you say “converts it to int later”, what exactly are you referring to?  There are multiple ways that could be done, so it isn’t clear which of them you mean.

Comment: Do you mean 'why bother converting a string variable to an int if you are just going to print out the results?' Because in that case, you wouldn't need to, but (as noted) if you want to do a comparison (which your code does), you better have a number, not a string. If you are asking why not use another method to convert to int, `std::stoi` is fast, easy, familiar, standard, handles pathological input elegantly etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of reasons people use `getline`, then convert the string to an `int` with `std::stoi` instead of extracting an `int` directly from the stream (like `std::cin >> nAge;`).

The first is that it can be a little bit easier to recover from errors this way. If you try to extract an `int` directly from the stream, but the user enters `six` instead of `6`, the stream will go into a failed state, and you'll need to extract the `six` from the stream *and* reset the stream before you can try again.

If you read a line, then use `stoi` to do the conversion, it's fairly easy to just read a line repeatedly until you get something can convert successfully.

It can also be somewhat clumsy if you try to mix reading things a line at a time with reading things an item at a time. For example:

```cpp
std::cout << "Please enter your age: ";
std::cin >> age;
std::cout << "Please enter your name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Assuming the user enters data roughly as intended, we can expect this to read the name as an empty string. The problem is that when we read the age, it read the digits and converted them to `age`. But that was followed by a new-line character, which hasn't been read yet--so when we call `getline`, it will see the new-line, and treat that as the end of the line, so `name` ends up empty. There are ways to avoid/fix this but they add a bit of clumsiness, so sometimes it's easier to just read all the data with `getline`, and convert it as needed afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! So it was not a meaningless behavior.